# How to force a font on an entire wordpress website (including woocommerce)

Tags: html, css, wordpress, woocommerce, fonts

I am trying to make my entire website have the same font, including Gutenberg blocks and all of WooCommerce. The problem is that I have the free version of Neve which doesn't allow to change the font of the entire website for free. I really don't want to spend $60 just to change fonts.

Is there anyway to force the font of the entire website using CSS or any plugin ? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Just use css to change font type, styling(bold,highlight,italic,etc) You can use class to specify classes or can set at  to make entire web with the same setting.

```css
/*set default font at <body>*/
body {font-family:Cursive ;
  
     }
```

```html
<body>
  <h1>Applying same font in entire website</h1>
  <p>Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old.</p>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the plugin [Custom Fonts](https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-fonts/) to upload your custom fonts on your WordPress site in multiple weights. You can also load your fonts from an external link with the same plugin.

Then, for example, you can target with CSS the elements you want to apply the font to, like this:

```
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
 font-family: 'My headings font';
}

p {
font-family: 'My body font';
} 

em {
font-family: 'My body italic font';
}
```